# Recurrent objects in Django

Tags: python, django, api, events

I need some help in order to manage adding a new feature on my website created in Django. I made a spendings tracker website where a user can add as many personalized spendings and budgets he/she likes but I have a problem. I want to make a user to have the possibility to create recurrent spendings and budgets. For example if a user creates a spending right now and he select to be recurrent the website should some how add in the next month the same spending at the same date. If I create now a new spending, next month on 20th September the website should add this automatically. Some help please.

Spending object in models.py file:

```
class Spending(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}\'s {self.name}'
```

Function that create a spending in views.py file:

```
@login_required
def create_spending(request):
    Spending.objects.create(user=request.user, name=request.POST['spending_name'],
                            category=request.POST['spending_category'], amount=request.POST['spending_amount'])
    return redirect('dashboard')
```

I know that I need to add a new boolean row to table Spending and some if cases in this function but I don't have the exact idea and I need some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Baiscally what I understood from your question is that you want to do some operation automatically without user intervention.

You can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/index.html): A distributed task queue which supports task scheduling.
[Celery Periodic Task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#:%7E:text=custom%20scheduler%20classes-,Introduction,entries%20in%20a%20SQL%20database.) to schedule your operation. To store your intervals you can use [django-celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will help you to store when to run task for a particular Spending.